# Why should the version tag be checked?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to make the test-network of hyperledger run and currently searching for mistakes of mine. The website of hyperledger instructs to "checkout the correct version tag" after cloning the fabric-sample repository:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#before-you-begin

What is the version tag and how/why check it? Cannot find any information about it and therefor ignored it until now.

Answer (score 0):

fabric-samples repo is having git tags for corresponding versions of Hyperledger Fabric. You can see all the tags [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tags). After cloning the repo, you have to checkout to the tag that is matching the fabric version.
For example, if you are using fabric 2.2.6, checkout to that tag like

```
git checkout v2.2.6
```